# Complex Plane: Clopen Subsubset Boundary

Tags: general-topology

**Problem**

Given an open subset $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$.

Then for clopen subsubset:
$$A\subseteq U:\quad A,U\setminus A\in\mathcal{T}(U)\implies\partial A\subseteq\partial U$$
How can I check this?

**Application**

This applies to spectral theory!

Comment: Your notation is a bit hard to interpret. Does $X^{\complement}$ mean the complement of $X$ with respect to $\mathbb{C}$? Does $\partial A^{\complement}$ mean $\partial (A^{\complement})$ or $(\partial A)^{\complement}$? If the former, why bother with the complement at all, we have $\partial X = \partial (X^{\complement})$ always. Are you, effectively, asking whether for a (relatively) clopen subset $A$ of an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$ the boundary of $A$ (boundary with respect to $\mathbb{C}$) is contained in the boundary of $U$?

Comment: Good point thank you!! :) *(I edited it!)*

Comment: YEEES, EXACTLY: That is what I'm asking!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B = U\setminus A$ and $F = \mathbb{C}\setminus U$. Then $A,B,U$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ and $F$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$. By the characterisation of the boundary of $M\subset X$ as

$$\partial M = \overline{M} \cap \overline{X\setminus M}$$

we find

$$\partial A = \overline{A} \cap (F\cup B) = \overline{A}\cap F \subset \overline{U}\cap F = \partial U$$

since $\mathbb{C}\setminus A = F\cup B$ is closed, and $B\cap \overline{A} = \varnothing$ by the openness of $B$ and $B\cap A = \varnothing$.

Comment: Great got it thank you!!! :) (+1)